# Patrones para structs, interfaces, metodos

Tags: go

Estoy empezando a manejarme con Go y me ha sido de gran ayuda el libro Concurrency in Go de Katherine Cox-Buday para avanzar más allá de lo básico, y ver aplicaciones prácticas y construir patrones con las primitivas de Go referidas a la concurrencia.

Mi pregunta es si alguien conoce o puede aconsejarme un texto similar en lo referente a los métodos, las interfaces y las structs. Se me hace aún un poco duro intentar interpretar y aprender de la librería standard, que supongo que será lo ideal... pero insisto, me cuesta.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve de ayuda, te dejo un enlace a un libro muy básico de inicialización a Go.
https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/9

Para las interfaces, te dejo estos dos enlaces que a mi me sirvieron de mucho:
https://medium.com/golangspec/interfaces-in-go-part-i-4ae53a97479c
https://medium.com/golangspec/interfaces-in-go-part-ii-d5057ffdb0a6

¡Espero que te sirvan!